# How to get listview values in other page.xaml

Tags: c#, listview, windows-phone-8.1

I have a list view, and I would like to pass the value when click.

```
public Lista()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    carregaLista();
}
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
}
public async void carregaLista()
{

    var local = Path.Combine(Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.Path, "hinos.sqlite");
    SQLiteAsyncConnection con = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(local, SQLiteOpenFlags.Create | SQLiteOpenFlags.ReadWrite);

    listaHinos.ItemsSource = await con.Table<hinos>().ToListAsync();
}

public void listaHinos_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail), listaHinos);
}
```

I am passing with this command:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail), listaHinos);
```

But I don't know how I get the `listaHinos` value when I click and open in other page.

> The other page is below.

```
public hinoDetail()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();

    }

    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        var result = e.Parameter as List<hinos>;
    }

    public async void mostraHino()
    {

    }
```

Comment: Should be in the NavigationEventArgs as an object. `List<hinos> items =e.Parameter as List<hinos>`

Comment: @William and this comand, i put on the second class to get values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the code above is from the screen you wish to navigate to? If so:

```
public hinoDetail()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

}

protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    hinos result = (e.Parameter as List<hinos>).FirstOrDefault(); //gets the first one only
   textBlock.Text = result.nameHino

}

public async void mostraHino()
{

}
```

Comment: for example , i need to declare this comand in the first class with listview ?

Comment: No this needs to go into the class of the page you wish to navigate to

Comment: Yes, although the var is not important. The list will be inside `result`

Comment: Sorry, but result is not showing up for use, i declared in navigationEventArgs, but how can i access... sry again, i am newbie with c# and windows application, it is my first @William

Comment: Can you update the question details with the code from the `hinoDetails` class? Ideally just this method `OnNavigatedTo`

Comment: ok... i edited the question and put the other class hinoDetail.

Comment: Ok looking at the code it should work fine. If it's the var which is causing confusion change the hinoDetail OnNavigationTo method to contain this: `List<hinos> result = e.Parameter as List<hinos>;`

Comment: yes, hinoDetail is the screen what i want to navigate, my code is equal your answer, but for exemple,. ( textBlock.Text = result.nameHino ) i would like to do this, but result not appers.

Comment: This is because result is in a List. So it will contain multiple types of hinos. If you want the first one only see the change I made above

Comment: thx , man with this line , the header of the list appers.
hinos result = (e.Parameter as List<hinos>).FirstOrDefault();
nomeHinoDetail.Text = result.nameHino;

Comment: now i got an error haha .... so man, thank you for the patience, now i will study this error.
"An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in SYSTEM.CORE.NI.DLL but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Value cannot be null."

Comment: hey man.. i found it .. i need pass it on selectionChanged "Frame.Navigate(typeof(hinoDetail), listaHinos.ItemsSource);"

Comment: In this case , i get the first value, but how can i get the value that i click in the listview ?

Comment: In listaHinos_SelectionChanged change it from listaHinos to listaHinos.SelectedItem